# Select color children TreeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

In this JS code I try to add all the nested elements of the parent to the green one, I try to add the class 'TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger'. Unfortunately, this only affects the first nesting, that is, if you expand the tree further, then the following elements are not added by pressing the 'TreeView-ActiveToweDanger' class.My head does not understand, I do not know what to think.

[TreeView Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSCSy.png)

```js
function getTreeViews(el, move) {
     $('.TreeView').each(function(i, e) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('TreeView-Active')) {
               $(this).removeClass('TreeView-Active');
          }
          if ($(this).hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger')) {
               $(this).removeClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
          }
     });
     el.addClass('TreeView-Active');

     if (el.attr('data-id') != 0 && !el.hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMove')) {
          var parent_id = el.parent('div').attr('id').split('TreeView-Move-Block-')[1];
          if ($('#move-row-' + parent_id).hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMove')) {
               el.addClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
          } else {
               var ActiveMove = $('.TreeView-ActiveMove');
               if (ActiveMove.length) {
                    var ActiveMoveld = ActiveMove.attr('data-id');
                    if (el.parents('#TreeView-Move-Block-' + ActiveMoveld).length) {
                         el.addClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

```css
.TreeView {
 padding: 5px 0 5px 15px;
}
.TreeView:hover {
 background: #e4ebfa;
}
.TreeView-Active {
 background: #e4ebfa;
}
.TreeView-ActiveMove {
 background: #ace6ac!important;
}
.TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger {
 background: #f58787!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="TreeView-Move-Block">
     <div class="TreeView clearfix pl-30 TreeView-ActiveMove" id="move-row-20" data-id="20" onclick="getTreeViews($(this), false)">
          Father
     </div>
     <div class="pl-30" id="TreeView-Move-Block-20">
         <div class="TreeView clearfix pl-30" id="move-row-17" data-id="17" onclick="getTreeViews($(this), false)">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Child-1
         </div>
         <div class="pl-30" id="TreeView-Move-Block-17">
              <div class="TreeView clearfix pl-30" id="move-row-21" data-id="21" onclick="getTreeViews($(this), false)">
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Child-2
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="TreeView clearfix pl-30" id="move-row-22" data-id="22" onclick="getTreeViews($(this), false)">
          Sister
     </div>
 </div>
```

update | **I came up with a solution, not ideal but working. Corrected JS. As it turned out not quite.**

update | **Once again corrected JS. From this we must build on.**

update | **Now 100% works.**

Comment: CSS part ? why don't u use jssnippet ?

Comment: Done. Made a snippet. In general, the above is a link to the screenshot.

Comment: where is the `pull-right` class in your css and html, it doesnt exist !

Comment: You could not pay attention to this, but I removed the excess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вот мой полностью рабочий код**

```
function getTreeViews(el, move) {
     $('.TreeView').each(function(i, e) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('TreeView-Active')) {
               $(this).removeClass('TreeView-Active');
          }
          if ($(this).hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger')) {
               $(this).removeClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
          }
     });
     el.addClass('TreeView-Active');

     if (el.attr('data-id') != 0 && !el.hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMove')) {
          var parent_id = el.parent('div').attr('id').split('TreeView-Move-Block-')[1];
          if ($('#move-row-' + parent_id).hasClass('TreeView-ActiveMove')) {
               el.addClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
          } else {
               var ActiveMove = $('.TreeView-ActiveMove');
               if (ActiveMove.length) {
                    var ActiveMoveld = ActiveMove.attr('data-id');
                    if (el.parents('#TreeView-Move-Block-' + ActiveMoveld).length) {
                         el.addClass('TreeView-ActiveMoveDanger');
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you reformulate this in english?